# Wait and switch cards in java

Tags: java, swing, cardlayout

I have a JFrame with `cardlayout` and two cards.
I want the first card to be displayed for 5 seconds and then switched to the second.

I used the following code:

```
CardLayout cards=new CardLayout();
panel.setLayout(cards);
panel.add(first,"first");
panel.add(second,"second");
cards.show(panel,"first");
Thread.sleep(5000);
cards.show(panel,"second");
```

However the second card is directly shown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Swing is single threaded. Youre blocking the `EDT` with the call to `Thread.sleep` preventing the first card from being painted. [Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) were designed to interact with Swing components. Use one instead to invoke [`CardLayout#show`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html#show%28java.awt.Container,%20java.lang.String%29) in the timer's `ActionListener`.

```
Timer timer = new Timer(5000, new ActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        cards.show(panel,"second");
    }
});
timer.setRepeats(false);
timer.start();
```

Read: [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/)

Comment: thanks a lot for code.
But now the second card never shows. even after 5 secs

Comment: The problem is in the code youre not showing us - please post a [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: Big appology,
It was a minor spelling mistake.
Thanx a lot for help !